# Cannot import Machine Key with Ubuntu 22.04? Previous versions such as 20.04.4 worked with no issue

Tags: 22.04, keys

When registering a public machine key with 22.04, I get the following error message:

```
root@jmoriarty-test:/home/jmoriarty# mokutil --import /home/jmoriarty/cct_lbsp_key.der --root-pw

Failed to get root password hash

root@jmoriarty-test:/home/jmoriarty#
```

This works without issues when executing the command above using the same key on the same machine and BIOS with 20.04.4 LTS.

Any ideas?

I am using SHA256 keys.  I just downloaded the mokutil source and noticed that generate_pw_hash file is done with a DEFAULT_CRYPT_METHOD.  I search for this define and found this.

src/mokutil.c:#define DEFAULT_CRYPT_METHOD SHA512_BASED

Does this mean the Machine Keys have to be SHA512 now for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Comment: More debugging reveals that mokutil uses the /etc/shadow file to retrieve the encrypted password for "root" user.  I checked the /etc/shadow file and the "root:" entry is in the file.  This is beginning to look like a mokutil compatibility issue with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.  

Ubuntu 22.04 mokutil version = 0.4.0-1ubuntu2.

Can someone take a look at this?

Comment: The --root-pw supplemental option for mokutil is broken for Ubuntu 22.04.  I hope someone at Ubuntu provides a fix for this before Ubuntu 22.04.1 is released August 4th, 2022.

Comment: Can someone from Ubuntu confirm this is a bug.  If not, then please respond with working as expected.  I need an answer since this functionality is deviating from previous Ubuntu OS versions and/or kernels.